# How to fix Key error in Kmeans Clustering

Tags: python, pandas, k-means

I am using sklearn library for Kmeans after fitting data on Kmeans and then generating labels. I have appended the labels as Cluster label in the data set. I want to print date and name of state in each clusters. I have made 4 clusters. After printing of states in cluster 0.I get an error of KeyError = 416 after that. I don't get why this error has occurred. Please help me resolve it.

[image: Dataset]

```
for i in range(0,2):
    print("\nCountries in Cluster " + str(i))
    for j in range(0,len(data)):
        if data['Cluster label'][j] == i: 
            print(data['date'][j],data['state'][j])
```

Here is the output on running the above code on the dataset. After printing states and date that comes under cluster 0 an error is generated. I am not getting what caused this error to occur.

```
Countries in Cluster 0
2020-01-21 Washington
2020-01-22 Washington
2020-01-23 Washington
2020-01-24 Illinois
2020-01-24 Washington
2020-01-25 California
2020-01-25 Illinois
2020-01-25 Washington
2020-01-26 Arizona
2020-01-26 California
2020-01-26 California
2020-01-26 Illinois
2020-01-26 Washington
...

Error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2894             try:
-> 2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

KeyError: 416

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-ef85b13c4238> in <module>
      2     print("\nCountries in Cluster " + str(i))
      3     for j in range(0,len(data)):
----> 4         if data['Cluster label'][j] == i:
      5             print(data['date'][j],data['state'][j])
      6 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    880 
    881         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 882             return self._get_value(key)
    883 
    884         if is_hashable(key):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
    987 
    988         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
--> 989         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
    990         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
    991 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:
-> 2897                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2898 
   2899         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 416
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that index 416 is **not actually present in **data****. Try resetting the index of dataframe before entering the for-loop. Also, it is most beneficial to stick to .loc() and .iloc() as the slicing tools in pandas dataframes.